# How to customize search Sidebar Facet layout in Dspace?

Tags: xslt, dspace

Theme: Mirage XMLUI personalized

I want to customize the layout (HTML / CSS) of faceted search, there is no XSLT files that allow customizes it but I could be wrong.

[image]

Comment: to do something like that

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to customize the CSS, you can find some styles defined in the following files

- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/static/css/discovery/discovery-style.css#L132-L148
- https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/css/style.css#L768-L1299

If you want to control the number of items that display or the ordering of items within a facet, you will want to change the facet definitions which are described on the following page.

- https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery